# Map n different values in range [0, 1] to unique integers in range [0, n-1] (used for 0-indexing)

Tags: python, indexing, range, mapping

**Problem statement:**

We want to map `n` different values in range `[0, 1]` to **unique** integers in range `[0, n-1]`. E.g., say we have the values `0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15`, where `n=4`. Multiplying them by 20 yields: `0, 1, 2, 3`.

**Note**:

In the above example the result are integers, however they do not need to be, e.g. the result `0.5, 1.3, 2.7, 3.8` is also valid because after this mapping we can simply apply `floor()` to transform them to integers).

**Goal**:

This mapping can be used to create integer indices from values between `[0,1]`.

Comment: Also specify the coding language used(for eg.; `python`, `ruby`) tag in your question for better understanding.

Comment: Do I get your question right? You are looking for a function that takes the maximum value of your list, divides it by `n-1` and finally multiplies every list value by the result?

Comment: Assign them in order? `zip(sorted(nums), range(len(nums)))` This is a strangle problem and I don't see how this is related to linalg per se. Sounds like a hw problem.

Comment: @BaileyParker `enumerate(sorted(nums))` does that as well

Comment: @dseuss The order of the tuples is flipped though, but yeah